# Sum dictionary values in python by specific keys

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I have the following list of dictionaries called 'assets':

```
assets = [
{
    "type": "site",
    "pcd_sector_id": 1,
    "cells": 3,
    "technology": "LTE"
},
{
    "type": "site",
    "pcd_sector_id": 2,
    "cells": 5,
    "technology": "LTE-Advanced"
},
{
    "type": "site",
    "pcd_sector_id": 2,
    "cells": 3,
    "technology": "LTE"
}
]
```

I want to sum the 'cells' for all possible technologies (there are >50). I've looked at plenty of questions but I couldn't find any that sum numerical values based on a string variable.

I know how to do this easily in Pandas, but I'm looking for a pure python solution.

Edit: Given the feedback, I've made some changes to the question and data. The desired output would have the number of cells by technology for each postcode sector:

```
aggregated = [
{
"pcd_sector_id": 1,
"LTE": 3,
"LTE-Advanced": 0
}
{
"pcd_sector_id": 2,
"LTE": 3,
"LTE-Advanced": 5
}
]
```

Comment: Can you provide the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is first retrieve all the "cells" items in a single list:

```
cells = [d['cells'] for d in assets]

# or

import operator

cells = map(operator.itemgetter('cells'), assets)
```

And then just sum them using the built-in `sum` function:

```
sum(d['cells'] for d in assets)

# or

sum(map(operator.itemgetter('cells'), assets))
```

Both approaches are good for smaller lists (I think the top one would be faster), but the bottom one is definitely faster for large lists:

```
$python3 -m timeit "assets = [{'cells': 1}] * 1000; import operator" "sum(d['cells'] for d in assets)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 67.4 usec per loop
$python3 -m timeit "assets = [{'cells': 1}] * 1000; import operator" "sum(map(operator.itemgetter('cells'), assets))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.5 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve specific column of dictionary and sum it up.

```
count =0
for i in assets:
    count = count + i['cells']
```

**[>>Demo<<](https://ideone.com/Luw85W)**

Answer (score 1):

One line solution:

```
>>> sum([asset['cells'] for asset in assets])
```

Comment: Remove the outer `[ ]`. Otherwise a temporary list is built which is not necessary.